# linux non recognize usb hdd

Tags: hard-disk, error-handling

First of all thank you for the help, and my apologize because I don't have a deep knowledge on this kind of things.

I've a Toshiba StoreE HDD USB drive that don't want to work.

When I use dmesg shows this:

```
[  192.789711] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  192.940101] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0939, idProduct=0b16, bcdDevice= 1.0f
[  192.940120] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  192.940136] usb 1-1.1: Product: StorE HDD
[  192.940151] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Toshiba
[  192.940165] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: 201005110631
[  192.947284] usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  192.948467] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.1:1.0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg | tail
[  211.371716] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x5 [current] 
[  211.371727] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 ASC=0x20 ASCQ=0x0 
[  211.371739] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x88 88 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff 80 00 00 00 08 00 00
[  211.371751] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 4294967168 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  211.376775] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[  211.376787] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x5 [current] 
[  211.376798] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 ASC=0x20 ASCQ=0x0 
[  211.376810] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x88 88 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff 80 00 00 00 08 00 00
[  211.376822] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 4294967168 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  211.376840] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 536870896, async page read
```

Also I try gsmartcontrol but don't recognize:

[image]

And if I run sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda shows this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [armv7l-linux-5.4.51-v7l+] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.12
Device Model:     ST31000528AS
Serial Number:    9VP6DVKD
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0203585d7
Firmware Version: CC44
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Thu Dec  3 09:29:28 2020 GMT

==> WARNING: A firmware update for this drive may be available,
see the following Seagate web pages:
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/207931en
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/213891en

SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

Read SMART Data failed: scsi error medium or hardware error (serious)

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status command failed: scsi error unsupported scsi opcode
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: UNKNOWN!
SMART Status, Attributes and Thresholds cannot be read.

Read SMART Log Directory failed: scsi error medium or hardware error (serious)

Read SMART Error Log failed: scsi error medium or hardware error (serious)

Read SMART Self-test Log failed: scsi error medium or hardware error (serious)

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

Any help?
As I said, I'm don't know what I'm doing (I read several similar post) but don't know more.

Thanks in advance!!

***EDIT***
I remove the enclosure and attach a external. after another dmesg shows this

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg | tail
[ 6592.600793] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unit Not Ready
[ 6592.600814] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x4 [current] 
[ 6592.600829] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 6592.602601] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6592.602626] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x4 [current] 
[ 6592.602641] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 6592.604607] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6592.604624] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : 0x4 [current] 
[ 6592.604647] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 6592.608944] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

Thanks!

Comment: The error messages are pretty clear, I would think. Is the USB drive in an enclosure? You could try to switch to a different enclosure/adapter whatever is lying around to rule out the USB enclosure as the root cause. If you see the same messages with a different adapter your HDD is very likely broken.

Comment: Thanks @eblock yes, the HDD is on a aluminum enclosure. I'll open and try with a adapter.I'll update ASAP. Thanks again.

Comment: `blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 4294967168 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0` it's dead, Jim